# WP read more at the end of excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to put a read more.. at the end of excerpt so far no luck.

I've tried this which works okay but it put the read more... at the bottom of the excerpt.

```
the_excerpt();
echo '<a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Read More...</a>';
```

is there a way to do it like

```
the_excerpt("Read more..");
```

Answer (score 1):

put the following in your theme's functions.php.

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return ' <a class="read-more" href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">' . __('Read More', 'your-text-domain') . '</a>';
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

Comment: you have to add this function in your theme's functions.php

Comment: Yeah I know :) but its not showing at the end of the excerpt.

Comment: do you have a chance to inspect the excerpt.. check whether it is hidden

Answer (score 0):

here is what you want

```
function excerpt($limit) {
      $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
      if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
      } else {
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
      } 
      $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
      return $excerpt;
    }

    function content($limit) {
      $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
      if (count($content)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($content);
        $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
      } else {
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
      } 
      $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
      $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
      return $content;
    }
```

Usage :

```
<?php echo excerpt(25); ?>
```

Source : http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/limiting-the-number-of-words-in-your-excerpt-or-content-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try the recommended way provided by WordPress ::

Excerpts (teasers) can be shown on WordPress through two methods:

1. Keeping the the_content() template tag and inserting a `quicktag called more` at your desired "cut-off" point when editing the post.
2. By replacing the the_content() template tag with the_excerpt().

And for changing the "Read More" text link you can make use of the parameters used with `the_content` like this

`<?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?>`

Source => http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your functions.php file.

```
<?php
// Custom Excerpt 
function excerpt($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
array_pop($excerpt);
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
} else {
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
} 
$excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
return $excerpt;
}
?>
```

Usage :

```
<?php echo excerpt(25); ?>
```

Source: http://www.e2soft.com/blog/custom-excerpt-and-content-limit-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I got another way to display limited excerpt by character. Here is the functions.php file code.

```
function get_excerpt(){
$excerpt = get_the_content();
$excerpt = preg_replace(" (\[.*?\])",'',$excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_shortcodes($excerpt);
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, 100);
$excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, " "));
$excerpt = trim(preg_replace( '/\s+/', ' ', $excerpt));
$excerpt = $excerpt.'... <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">Read More</a>';
return $excerpt;
}
```

After this you need to add where you want to display your customized character by character.

```
<?php echo get_excerpt(); ?>
```

@ http://www.e2soft.com/forum/question/how-to-set-custom-excerpt-and-content-limit-wordpress/